# Add Class to div after another class with animation is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a button that when I pressed it, it will add a class with animation into the image. I made another button and I want to add another class to the image which will revert the image back to its original size. But the second class is not adding into it, I've tried to remove the previous class but it's unremovable after adding into image.

Any way to add the second class into the image?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#profile').click(function() {
    $('.imageone').addClass('move');
    $('.imageone').removeClass('imageone');
  })

  $('#back').click(function() {
    $('.imageone').removeClass('move');
    $('.imageone').addClass('goback');
  })
})
```

```css
.move {
  animation: scale 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0pt;
  }
  to {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -142pt;
    transform: scale(1.16, 1.23);
    left: 0pt;
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }
}

.goback {
  animation: goback 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes goback {
  from {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -142pt;
    transform: scale(1.16, 1.23);
    left: 0pt;
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }
  to {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0pt;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageone">
  <img src="images.png" class="imageone" alt="liam">
</div>
<div id="textprofile">
  <a href="#" class="button" id="border">
    <p id="profile">Visit Profile</p>
  </a>
</div>
<p id="back">go back</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with same id so when you add an event listener using ID selector, javascript cannot handle such a thing because you are supposed to have each ID only once in HTML pages. Try to change your selector and also change IDs.

Comment: Hi sorry that was my mistake that typed that wrong, it was actually 2 different ID. And to clarify the animation of first class has added successfully, just the second class isn't working

Comment: Try to inspect element and see if class is added to the element at all. Maybe your problem would have something to do with CSS

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the existing class and add a new class to it. You have added a class first with the existing one so it will get appended and after you are trying to remove that class "imageone" which will not get removed. So try removing imageone first and add the move class. Provide an Id to an img element and do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#profile').click(function() {
  $('#imageone').removeClass('imageone');
  $('#imageone').addClass('move');
  })

  $('#back').click(function() {
  $('#imageone').removeClass('move');
  $('#imageone').addClass('goback');
  })
 })
```

Comment: Hello I've provided an ID for the image but it's still not working.

Comment: In the html code u mentioned above doesn't have Id please have a look <img src="images.png" class="imageone" alt="liam">

Answer (score 0):

plz try this code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#profile').click(function() {
    $('.imageone').addClass('move');
    $('.imageone').removeClass('goback');
  });

  $('#back').click(function() {
    $('.imageone').removeClass('move');
    $('.imageone').addClass('goback');
  });
});
```

Comment: its working for me in local.. can u plz add this in codepen?

Comment: which browser you are checking?